# CMake - Custom command to executable

Tags: c, cmake, makefile, linker, cross-compiling

I'm trying to add create a CMake executable from a file linked with `add_custom_command`. 
Basically I'm creating a `.ROB` linked file with an `add_custom_command`. This is done throught a special linker that only wants a `.cmd` as an input (thought the `custom_command`). 
I need to a make it into a target for later use in a `$<TARGET_FILE:tgt>`.

```
# Link my custom target
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myFile.ROB
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_LINKER} ${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} -c ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myFile.cmd -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/myFile.ROB
)

myFile.ROB  -> myTarget ?
```

I tried multiple solutions with `IMPORTED` targets bu t no luck so far.

Comment: There's no need for a `makefile` tag here: you're using cmake so there's no readable `makefile` involved (even if you use a makefile generator, there's nothing about makefiles in your cmake files).